# why hyperic can't auto-discover my Jboss AppSvr?

Tags: jboss, hyperic

I installed JBoss AS on xx.xx.12.48. 
I launched ./bin/run.sh -b xx.xx.12.48. 
The JMX web console indicates everything is OK.

On xx.xx.12.49, I installed Hyperic (latest).
I installed Hyperic agent on xx.xx.12.48
I can see both Hyperic agents, on both servers.
But ther's nothing about my JBoss AS server !!!

**Why can't Hyperic Auto-Discover finds my JBoss server ?**
Is there a simple way to configure ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To force Hyperic HQ Agent to detect JBoss, you have to edit conf/agent.properties

jboss.installpath=C:/jboss

Then, log into your Hyperic HQ Server and manually add the jboss server under inventory.
[image]

Give it few minutes, the local agent will pick up the instruction and look for the jboss server.

Answer (score 0):

because you install the new server,but agent did not know,so the hqserver do not know neither.
You need to configure the agent.properties in the agent installed machine.Refer official document:
http://support.hyperic.com/display/EVO/Configure+Agent+-+Server+Communication+Interactively